# All cohomology of quadrics comes from algebraic cycles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've read in a number of place now the statement that all cohomology of quadrics (complex projective ones) comes from algebraic cycles, but I cannot find any source for this. So I hope someone here can point me to a book/paper where this is explained.

Answer (score 10):

Let me try to outline the proof, and you can fill in the details. We take an $n$-dimensional smooth quadric hypersurface $Q$ sitting in $\mathbf P^{n+1}$.

1. By the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, for $k \neq n$, the restriction maps

$$H^k(\mathbf P^n, \mathbf Z) \rightarrow H^k(Q,\mathbf Z)$$ 
are isomorphisms, and so the cohomology groups of $Q$ in these degrees certainly come from algebraic cycles. Moreover, by the universal coefficient theorem this also shows that $H^k(X,\mathbf Z)$ is torsion-free for all $k$.

2. Using the normal bundle sequence

$$ T_Q \rightarrow T_{\mathbf P^n} \rightarrow N_Q $$

one computes the Euler characteristic of $Q$; together with the information from Step 1 above this shows that

$$ H^n(Q,\mathbf Z) = \begin{cases} \mathbf Z \oplus \mathbf Z \quad &\mbox{if $n$ is even} \\0 \quad &\mbox{if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}$$

3. Now it just remains to find two non-homologous cycles of middle dimension on an even-dimensional quadric. Thinking about the case $\operatorname{dim} Q=2$, where $Q \cong \mathbf P^1 \times \mathbf P^1$, gives you a big hint about what these should be!

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Could you just tell me roughly how to calculate the Euler characteristic from the normal bundle sequence? (I'm not very familiar with this material at all, so please excuse my ignorance.)

Comment: Sure. The Euler characteristic is the same as the degree of the top Chern class of the tangent bundle $T_Q$. If you know the Chern classes of $T_{\mathbf P^n}$ and $N_Q$ then you can use the Whitney sum formula to calculate the Chern classes of $T_Q$. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does. Now I know the terms and concepts I'll have to figure out in order to do this:p Thanks again, this helps me a lot:)

Comment: One last question: where do you use that we are working with a quadric?

Comment: This is encoded in the Chern class of $N_Q$, which determines the Euler characteristic and in turn the rank of $H^n$.

Comment: Dear @Nefertiti, I try to calculate the Euler characteristic $\chi(Q)$ of the quadric using the normal sequence suggested in your answer, but didn't get the desired result. Here is the simplest case: consider $Q\subset \mathbb P^3$ quadric surface, whose Euler characteristic $\chi(Q)=4$. On the other hand, the Chern class of $\mathbb P^3$ is $c(\mathbb P^3)=1+4x+6x^2+4x^3$, and the normal bundle $N_Q$ is $\mathcal{O}(2)$ on projective space restricted to $Q$, which is a degree 4 line bundle, so its Chern class is $c(N_Q)=1+4x$.

Comment: But if we expand the quotient $c(\mathbb P^3)/c(N_Q)$, we find the coefficient of $x^2$ is 6, surprisingly. I couldn't figure out where I was wrong, could you give me a hint?

Comment: Never mind, I think I have figured it where I was wrong: I shouldn't write $c(N_Q)=1+4x$, the coefficient $4$ will come out eventually paring with the fundamental class. I am tempted to write out a proof for your middle dimensional cohomology argument, but I'd rather let the reader work out on their own. One can refer to [Akhil's blog] (https://amathew.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/the-cohomology-of-projective-hypersurfaces/) It's a pretty good exercise! Thanks for your solution, Nefertiti.